# SQLite database remote access

Tags: database, sqlite, web-services, sqlalchemy, rdbms

I have a SQLite database on my local machine and my web services running on the same machine access it using SQLAlchemy like this:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///{}'.format('mydatabase.db'), echo=True)
```

We are planning to host our web services on a separate machine from where the database is hosted. How can we make this 'mydabata.db' be accessible for our web services remotely for my web services? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From SQLite [when to use](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html) docs:

> **Situations Where A Client/Server RDBMS May Work Better**
>
> - Client/Server Applications
>
> If there are many client programs sending SQL to the same database over a network, then use a client/server database engine instead of SQLite. SQLite will work over a network filesystem, but because of the latency associated with most network filesystems, performance will not be great. Also, file locking logic is buggy in many network filesystem implementations (on both Unix and Windows). If file locking does not work correctly, two or more clients might try to modify the same part of the same database at the same time, resulting in corruption. Because this problem results from bugs in the underlying filesystem implementation, there is nothing SQLite can do to prevent it.
>
> A good rule of thumb is to avoid using SQLite in situations where the same database will be accessed directly (without an intervening application server) and simultaneously from many computers over a network.

SQLite works well for embedded system or at least when you use it on the same computer. IMHO you'll have to migrate to one of the larger SQL solutions like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/), [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) or [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/). If you've generated all your queries though the ORM (SQLAlchemy) then there will be no problem migrating to another RDBMS. But even if wrote SQL queries too there should not be much problems because all these RDBMSes use very similar dialects (unlike Microsoft's T-SQL). And since SQLite is **lite** it supports only a subset of what other RDBMSes support so there should not be a problem.